# Seeking a closed expression for a combinatorial sum

Tags: combinatorics

Is there a simple closed expression for the following sum?
$$\sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor\frac n2\rfloor}{n\choose i}{n-i\choose i}$$

I can see that this is the constant term in $\big(\frac 1x+1+x\big)^n$. But this is no closer to a simple close expression I am seeking.

Comment: There is a giant OEIS page about that term...

Comment: @Dirk: I am not familiar with how to search for a particular general expression in OEIS. Also, even if there is a simple expression, how does one derive that?

Comment: Compute the first few terms for $n=1,2,3,4,5,6,...$ and put these into OEIS. It will give you http://oeis.org/A002426. I don't claim that there is an easy, closed form, but if there is, your best chance would be to find it there or in one of the sources mentioned there.

Comment: @Dirk: I see. Appreciate the explanation. By the way, did you downvote and voted to close the question? If so, is your rationale the answer could be found in OEIS?

Comment: I did downvote because there isn't any own effort shown, but I did not vote to close. :)

Comment: @Dirk: I tried the generating function route but did not get anywhere in terms of obtaining a simple closed expression. I have now put my failed attempt in the question.

Comment: To people vote to close: How is this question off-topic as in not pertaining to mathematics? It is a combinatorial sum, one of THE topic of combinatorics which is a main branch of mathematics.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We use the *coefficient of* operator $[z^i]$ to denote the coefficient of $z^i$ of a series. This way we can write for instance
\begin{align*}
[z^i](1+z)^n=\binom{n}{i}\tag{1}
\end{align*}

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{i=0}^{\left\lfloor \frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor}}&\color{blue}{\binom{n}{i}\binom{n-i}{i}}\tag{2}\\
> &=\sum_{i=0}^{n}\binom{n}{i}[z^i](1+z)^{n-i}\tag{3}\\
> &=[z^0](1+z)^n\sum_{i=0}^{n}\binom{n}{i}\left(\frac{1}{z(1+z)}\right)^i\tag{4}\\
> &=[z^0](1+z)^n\left(1+\frac{1}{z(1+z)}\right)^{n}\tag{5}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=[z^{n}](1+z+z^2)^n}\tag{6}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (3) we apply the *coefficient of* operator according to (1). We also set the upper limit to $n$ without changing anything, since $\binom{n-i}{i}=0$ if $i>\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor$.
- In (4) we use the rule $[z^{p-q}]A(z)=[z^p]z^qA(z)$.
- In (5) we apply the binomial theorem.
- In (6) we do some simplifications and use again the rule as in (3).

> We observe the binomial sum (2) represents essentially *[central trinomial coefficients](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CentralTrinomialCoefficient.html)*
>   \begin{align*}
> [z^n](1+z+z^2)^n
> \end{align*}
>   for which there is *no closed form* available.

**Notes from the experts:**

> D.E. Knuth gives in *[Concrete Mathematics](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~r97002/temp/Concrete%20Mathematics%202e.pdf)*, Appendix A 7.56 the following representation of a more general expression
>
> \begin{align*}
> [z^n](a+bz+cz^2)^n=[z^n]\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-2bz+(b^2-4ac)z^2}}
> \end{align*}
>
> He states that according to the paper *[Hypergeometric Solutions of Linear Recurrences with Polynomial Coeffcients](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.374.8662&rep=rep1&type=pdf)* by Marko Petkovšek there exists a closed form (more precisely: a closed form solution as a finite sum of hypergeometric terms) if and only if
>   $$\color{blue}{abc(b^2-4ac)=0}$$
>
> In case of central trinomial coefficients we have $a=b=c=1$. Since then the expression $abc(b^2-4ac)=-3\ne 0$
>   there is no such closed form in particular for the central trinomial coefficients.

Comment: Wow, a thorough solution. +1 and accepted. The link to the hypergeometric solution paper however seems wrong.

Comment: @Hans: Thanks for your nice comment and the credit. :-) I've updated the link.

Comment: Good research. (+1)

Comment: @MarkoRiedel: Many thanks, Marko. :-)

Answer (score 2):

As other people recommended, I computed a few terms by computer and it gives [A002426](http://oeis.org/A002426), which seems that there's no exact formula for it. The generating function is 
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-2x-3x^{2}}}
$$
and we also have an asymptotic formula
$$
a(n) \sim 3^{n}\sqrt{\frac{3}{4\pi n}}
$$

Comment: Can you give a derivation of the asymptotic formula, perhaps from the generating function?